# a simple inequality in Arthur Engel's book

Tags: inequality

I was reading *Problem solving strategies* by Arthur Engel and got stuck on checking the colored inequality which is supposed to be inferred by using arithmetic mean-geometric mean inequality

$$ x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n+y_n}{2}, \quad y_{n+1}=\sqrt{x_{n+1}y_n}   $$
$$x_n<y_n \implies x_{n+1}<y_{n+1}, \quad \color{red}{y_{n+1}-x_{n+1}<\frac{y_n-x_n}{4}} $$
I tried some stupid things but don't think posting them here would do any good

Comment: Did you try plugging in everything until it's a term in $x_n, y_n$? (I haven't checked it.)

Comment: @ Qi Zhu yes I did but it just got more complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the AM-GM inequality, $$y_{n+1} = \sqrt{x_{n+1}y_n} < \frac{x_{n+1} + y_n}{2}$$ Thus $$y_{n+1} - x_{n+1} < \frac{y_n - x_{n+1}}{2} = \frac{1}{2}\left[y_n - \frac{x_n + y_n}{2}\right] = \frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{y_n - x_n}{2}\right] = \frac{y_n - x_n}{4}$$